# GrantResourceOwnerCredentials not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, token, owin

I've inherited from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and overwritten as follows:

```
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.OwinContext.Set<string>("oauth:client", "test");

        context.Validated("blah");
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {

        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

        //using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        //{
        //    IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context., context.Password);

        //    if (user == null)
        //    {
        //        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        //        return;
        //    }
        //}

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }

    public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.IsTokenEndpoint)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "POST" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", new[] { "accept", "authorization", "content-type" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.RequestCompleted();

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
    }
    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {

            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }


        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

My startup looks like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };
        this.ConfigureOAuth(app);

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new xyzReportingAutherizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication
        (
            new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider()
            }
        );

    }
```

Any idea why GrantResourceOwnerCredentials is not firing? The goal is right now to generate an access token for future use. Authentication for that called is custom. (It's server to server, sharing a private key)

This is how I call it:

[image: Postman]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```
public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
{
    ....
    context.RequestCompleted();
    ....
 }
```

Actually ends the response right then and there. Removing that line did the trick.